# MeteorJS Bcrypt vs Pure Javascript Bcrypt ? Speed and Security

Tags: node.js, meteor, bcrypt

I'm new to meteorJS and am following a tutorial that suggests to use meteor's user login set up (the command is: `meteor add accounts-ui accounts-password`), this appears to be similar to passport or devise (for ruby). But I am getting the warning:

```
W20170514-13:03:03.163(-4)? (STDERR) Note: you are using a pure-JavaScript implementation of bcrypt.
W20170514-13:03:04.713(-4)? (STDERR) While this implementation will work correctly, it is known to be
W20170514-13:03:04.714(-4)? (STDERR) approximately three times slower than the native implementation.
W20170514-13:03:04.714(-4)? (STDERR) In order to use the native implementation instead, run
W20170514-13:03:04.715(-4)? (STDERR) 
W20170514-13:03:04.716(-4)? (STDERR)   meteor npm install --save bcrypt
W20170514-13:03:04.716(-4)? (STDERR) 
W20170514-13:03:04.717(-4)? (STDERR) in the root directory of your application.
```

Given that the pure javascript bcrypt is slower than meteor bcrypt does that effect security at all? Is it more secure to use pure js bcrypt? How can I test this?

Comment: Now that's funny, it happened to me yesterday. I tried to ```meteor add npm-bcrypt``` but I kept having this Note asking me to install the direct npm package. I am interested in the outcome tho. Have you tried the meteor package for it?

Answer (score 1):

A speed difference of 3x does not make a substantial difference, Bcrypt should consume about 100ms or compute time compared to a few micro-seconds for a hash. It is all about consuming compute time several orders of magnitude more than just a hash.

Comment: Especially important consideration, if you run your meteor app on an infrastructure which bills you by computation, which is very common nowadays.

Comment: The important consideration is security, it is the required CPU time that creates the security over just a hash. So, yes you have to pay for security. If you are not willing to pay then please tell your clients that you are to cheap to protect them.

Answer (score 0):

On some hardware the Javascript implementation will be significantly slower. I had to use the native lib on Raspberry because the JS lib simply turned login unusable.

Best is to run a test on your target architecture, don't rely on estimations.